# Mathjax - Excluding some files and folders from local installation

Tags: mathjax, mathml

On a local installation of `MathJax` on a Windows 10 desktop, if we are using `tex-chtml.js` file to display math, which other files and folders (if any) can we remove from the following `es5` folder?

**List of all Subfolders and files of es5 folder of MathJax local installation**:

```
a11y
adaptors
input
output
sre
ui
215978 core.js
5090 latest.js
17118 loader.js
644009 mml-chtml.js
1590983 mml-svg.js
259775 node-main.js
27990 startup.js
955538 tex-chtml-full.js
797631 tex-chtml.js
808783 tex-mml-chtml.js
1755757 tex-mml-svg.js
1902512 tex-svg-full.js
1744605 tex-svg.js
```

Comment: I think that deleting any files from there is not a good idea. Mostly because it's hard to predict exactly which files MathJax will use (I've seen it differing slightly depending on context and configuration). Also, even if you decide on a configuration now and deletes some files, perhaps you change your mind in the future and alters the config so that MathJax wants to use a different file that is then missing. Since MathJax 3 is quite small in size, what is the reason to why you want to delete files?

Comment: @fast-reflexes My software is using MathJax internally and currently the size of `es5` folder of Mathjax is about 17MB that is quite big for that software. Since software is displaying math using `tex-chtml.js` only I was wondering if we really need files like `1902512 tex-svg-full.js` or `1744605 tex-svg.js` (or some other files/folder in `es5`) for example.

Comment: You can use a CDn if you're online, then you won't have to store anything ... Otherwise, just delete things and check whether your use case works as it should or not until you can't delete more :)

Comment: @fast-reflexes It's an offline program. Doing trial and error by deleting some files and verifying may not be a good option since (as you mentioned earlier) you may not know what may break since you don't have control of what math expression a user may be using. Probably mathjax team can tell what may or may not be deleted if using `tex-chtml.js` only for rendering math.